# Why Are My Random List Items Always Identical?

Tags: pgfmath, random-numbers

I have a list and then two randomly selected items from them.

But those two items are always the same. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
 \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\newcommand{\InitVariables}
{%
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{List}{{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}}
\pgfmathrandomitem{\VarA}{List}
\pgfmathrandomitem{\VarB}{List}
}



\begin{document}


ATTEMPT ONE
\InitVariables

Variable A is \VarA .

Variable B is \VarB .


ATTEMPT TWO
\InitVariables

Variable A is \VarA .

Variable B is \VarB .

ATTEMPT THREE
\InitVariables

Variable A is \VarA .

Variable B is \VarB .

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`\pgfmathrandomitem` doesn't actually define `\varA` to be a randomly selected item, it defines it to *choose* such an item, and then `\VarB` gets the same definition, both are defined to be

```
> \VarB=macro:
->\csname pgfmath@randomlist@List@\pgfmath@randomtemp \endcsname .
```

as shown by the `\show`.

Here as the items are unexpandable you cansimply edef expand the definitions to get the actual values into the macros, as shown by the 2nd and 4th `\show`.

```
> \VarA=macro:
->5.
```

example document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
 \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\newcommand{\InitVariables}
{%
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{List}{{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}}
\pgfmathrandomitem{\VarA}{List}
\show\VarA
\edef\VarA{\VarA}
\show\VarA
\pgfmathrandomitem{\VarB}{List}
\show\VarB
\edef\VarB{\VarB}
\show\VarB
}



\begin{document}


ATTEMPT ONE
\InitVariables

Variable A is \VarA .

Variable B is \VarB .


ATTEMPT TWO
\InitVariables

Variable A is \VarA .

Variable B is \VarB .

ATTEMPT THREE
\InitVariables

Variable A is \VarA .

Variable B is \VarB .

\end{document}
```

Comment: But why, in that case, does it always choose the same item randomly twice? If `\VarA` is 'choose a random item' rather than some random item and `\VarB` is 'choose a random item' rather than some random item, then `\VarA \VarB` is 'choose a random item choose a random item'. So it should choose a random item twice and they shouldn't always be the same.

Comment: @cfr it picks a random number in `\pgfmath@randomtemp ` then defines varA to choose the \pgfmath@randomtemp'th item, then it puts another random number into \pgfmath@randomtemp  again and defines varB to chooose the \pgfmath@randomtemp 'th item so varA and varB both get defined to choose the \pgfmath@randomtemp 'th ite and \pgfmath@randomtemp  is the second random number calculated