# Strange exit code for https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/393239

Tags: errors

I'm trying to compile the example from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/393239 with pdflatex.

I get exit code 1, which suggests the compilation did not succeed, but texstudio does not show any error. I also searched the .log file for the term "error" but only found a single occurrence (in the description of a package "Providing info/warning/error messages")

What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
 \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\newcommand{\InitVariables}
{%
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{List}{{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}}
\pgfmathrandomitem{\VarA}{List}
\show\VarA
\edef\VarA{\VarA}
\show\VarA
\pgfmathrandomitem{\VarB}{List}
\show\VarB
\edef\VarB{\VarB}
\show\VarB
}



\begin{document}


ATTEMPT ONE
\InitVariables

Variable A is \VarA .

Variable B is \VarB .


ATTEMPT TWO
\InitVariables

Variable A is \VarA .

Variable B is \VarB .

ATTEMPT THREE
\InitVariables

Variable A is \VarA .

Variable B is \VarB .

\end{document}
```

---

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2018/09/10 v0.29 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
```

Comment: Remove `\show\VarA` and `\show\VarB`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\show` is essentially a user induced error message

Comment: works, thanks! I have to wait 10 minutes before I'm allowed to accept