# Saving Random Numbers in xsim for Solutions

Tags: random-numbers, xsim

I'm trying to create exercise sheets with random numbers and `xsim`. Each time I generate random numbers, though, the variables are overwritten to create new exercises (desired), but also overwritten so that all solutions only contain values from the final exercise (not desired).

How do I "save" the values of the solutions as they're generated?

I am aware that this maybe somewhat similar to [one of my prior threads](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393237/why-are-my-random-list-items-always-identical), but I tried to follow the `\edef...` syntax advice from there and it did not seem to work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{pgf}

\usepackage{pgffor}
    \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\usepackage{xsim}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


\newcommand{\InitVariables}
    {   \pgfmathrandominteger{\PartA}{0}{10}
            \edef\PartA{\PartA}
        \pgfmathrandominteger{\PartB}{0}{10}
            \edef\PartB{\PartB}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Sum}{int(\PartA + \PartB)}
            \edef\Sum{\Sum}
        }

\newcommand{\Exercise}{$\PartA+\PartB=?$}

\newcommand{\Solution}{$\PartA+\PartB=\Sum$}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}


\InitVariables
\begin{exercise}
    \Exercise
    \end{exercise}

\begin{solution}
    \Solution
    \end{solution}


\InitVariables
\begin{exercise}
    \Exercise
    \end{exercise}

\begin{solution}
    \Solution
    \end{solution}

\printallsolutions

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `xsim` tries *very hard* to write verbatim the contents of the `solution` environment.

Comment: So should I try to save the `\Solution` as a string and have `xsim` print that? If yes, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to add a counter and create unique macro names using that counter. This counter needs to be reset before `\printallsolutions`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{pgf}

\usepackage{pgffor}
    \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\usepackage{xsim}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcounter{myex}

\newcommand{\InitVariables}{%
       \stepcounter{myex}%
       \pgfmathrandominteger{\PartA}{0}{10}%
       \expandafter\edef\csname PartA\number\value{myex}\endcsname{\PartA}%
       \pgfmathrandominteger{\PartB}{0}{10}%
       \expandafter\edef\csname PartB\number\value{myex}\endcsname{\PartB}%
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\Sum}{int(\PartA + \PartB)}%
       \expandafter\edef\csname Sum\number\value{myex}\endcsname{\Sum}%
        }

\newcommand{\Exercise}{$\csname PartA\number\value{myex}\endcsname+\csname PartB\number\value{myex}\endcsname=?$}

\newcommand{\Solution}{\stepcounter{myex}%
$\csname PartA\number\value{myex}\endcsname+\csname PartB\number\value{myex}\endcsname=
\csname Sum\number\value{myex}\endcsname$}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}


\InitVariables
\begin{exercise}
    \Exercise
    \end{exercise}

\begin{solution}
    \Solution
    \end{solution}


\InitVariables
\begin{exercise}
    \Exercise
\end{exercise}

\begin{solution}
    \Solution
\end{solution}

\setcounter{myex}{0}
\printallsolutions
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I look forward to reading this carefully over the next day or two.

Comment: I just tested the code and it works! I understand most of it, but not all. What does `\expandafter\edef` do? I am aware that `\edef` is in code I've written, but I don't actually know what it does on its own either.

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything This code creates macros of the type `\PartA1`, `\PartA2` and so on, where `1`, `2` is the value of the counter `myex`. This makes the macros unique, and prevents them from being overwritten. One cannot say in TeX `\edef\PartA1{9}`, and even if we were working with roman numbers, we would have to compose the macro name. This is what `\expandafter\edef\csname PartA\number\value{myex}\endcsname{\PartA}%` does. `\csname something\endcsname` "creates" a macro `\something`. ...

Comment: We want to first "create" the macro and then assign it a value with `\edef`. This is what `\expandafter` does: it basically says wait with `\edef` until I have looked at, or, more precisely, expanded, what comes after it. Otherwise `\edef` would only see `\csname` and not  `\PartA1`, say.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/519/194703) has a very decent description of this trick. (Note that pgf keys are based on the same mechanism, and we could have used them here, too.)

Comment: Ok, I will need to study the answers here a little more, but it is clear that this is all, in principle, a very efficient solution. The MWE provided in the OP, though, has far fewer variables than what I originally intended, which is this answer key. https://www.overleaf.com/read/wfvcjkmtvmvd . [Each time you recompile, random numbers should generate a new file.] Do I need to just insert all the counter, `\expand\edef`, `\csname...` stuff in for each variable individually?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything I think that there is no way to avoid defining unique macros in one way or another. Otherwise they will be just overwritten, as you saw in your question. However, what can definitely be done is to make the generation of these unique macros more convenient/automatic. What is most convenient depends on the actual use case.

Comment: What are these ways to make it more convenient/automatic?

Comment: Another question: Why is `\stepcounter{myex}` necessary within `\Solution` but not in `\Exercise`?