# xsim, counters, and TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, counters, xsim

In [my previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546338/saving-random-numbers-in-xsim-for-solutions), I asked how to save random numbers for the `xsim` package.

Now I would like to know how to do that when those random numbers are inserted into a `TikZ` picture.

What about my counter is failing? That is, why is it only printing the solutions from the final exercise?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}

\usepackage{pgffor}
    \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{xsim}



\newcounter{ExNum}

\newcommand{\InitVariables}{%
    \stepcounter{ExNum}
    \pgfmathrandominteger{\IntegerPoint}{3}{10}
        \expandafter\edef\csname IntegerPoint\number\value{ExNum}\endcsname{\IntegerPoint}
    }


\newcommand{\NumberLine}{%

    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1]
    
    \draw[thick] (0,0)--(10,0);
    
    \foreach \x in {0,1,2}{
        \node at (\x,-1) {\large \x};
        }

    \foreach \x in {0,1,2,...,10}{
        \draw[thick] (\x,-0.35)--(\x,0.35);
        }

        
    \filldraw [red, opacity=0.4]
          (\csname IntegerPoint\number\value{ExNum}\endcsname,0) circle (0.15cm) ;
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }



\newcommand{\Exercise}{%
    \NumberLine
    }

\newcommand{\Solution}{%
    $\csname IntegerPoint\number\value{ExNum}\endcsname$    
    }




\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\begin{document}

Where is the dot?

\InitVariables
\begin{exercise}
    \Exercise
    \end{exercise}
    
\begin{solution}
    \Solution
    \end{solution}


\InitVariables
\begin{exercise}
    \Exercise
    \end{exercise}
    
\begin{solution}
    \Solution
    \end{solution}


\printallsolutions

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As in the previous question this is a matter of expansion and timing. The solution in both cases is `\Solution`. `\Solution` refers to the current value of the counter `ExNum` which at the time of printing the solutions unfortunately is the same for all exercises: the last value it has been set to before `\printallsolutions`.

We could try to expand the body of the solution environments. But I suggest another solution. Instead of a new counter use something that is unique for an exercise/solution pair. `xsim` already provides something: `\ExerciseID`.

Below is a modified version of your code which uses that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\usepackage{xsim}

\newcommand{\InitVariables}{%
  \pgfmathrandominteger{\IntegerPoint}{3}{10}%
}

\newcommand{\NumberLine}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1]
    \draw[thick] (0,0)--(10,0);
    \foreach \x in {0,1,2}{
      \node at (\x,-1) {\large \x};
    }
    \foreach \x in {0,1,2,...,10}{
      \draw[thick] (\x,-0.35)--(\x,0.35);
    }
    \filldraw [red, opacity=0.4] (\IntegerPoint,0) circle (0.15cm) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\Exercise}{%
  \NumberLine
  \expandafter\xdef\csname IntegerPoint\ExerciseID\endcsname{\IntegerPoint}%
}

\newcommand{\Solution}{%
  $\csname IntegerPoint\ExerciseID\endcsname$%
}

\begin{document}

Where is the dot?

\InitVariables
\begin{exercise}
  \Exercise
\end{exercise}
    
\begin{solution}
  \Solution
\end{solution}

\InitVariables
\begin{exercise}
  \Exercise
\end{exercise}
    
\begin{solution}
  \Solution
\end{solution}

\printallsolutions

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks perfect. Thanks! I will take a closer look tonight and tomorrow and will report back here. :)